# Finding ships sailing from Germany to Brazil between 1824 to 1830?

Tags: 19th-century, germany, emigration, brazil

Is it possible to find the names of ships used to transport German emigrants to Brazil in the period of 1824 to 1830?

I am specially looking for ships in the period 1827-1829.

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE!  If you want to learn more about how to use the site, see the [help].  You do not need to sign your questions because the system signs them for you with your user card.  I have edited your title and message a little to make it more clear.  Once you get answers, you can say thank you by upvoting the answers that are helpful to you. Hope you enjoy the site!

Comment: Relevant: https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/8039/6485, especally the answer

Comment: Are you looking for a particular ship? Or for a particular family?

Comment: Hi, I´m looking specially for ships in the 1827-1829 years. Tks.

Comment: As it stands I think your question seems to be looking for a list of ships, rather than a particular ship or a particular family?  This may make it too broad for focused Q&A and lead to its closure.