# Finding passenger list of ship with German immigrants to Brazil in 1824

Tags: 19th-century, germany, immigration, brazil

I got the important information: name of the ship (George Friedrich), it's commandant, it's capitan (Johann Peter Christian Rosilius) the date and place of departure and arrival (Altona Port Germany 27/06/1824 to Rio de Janeiro Brazil 11/10/1824).

How can I find the documents with the personal name of the passengers?

I only know that some members of the Peters family were on board, but not their names!

Comment: Related: https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/13266/finding-ships-sailing-from-germany-to-brazil-between-1824-to-1830?rq=1

Comment: @farewell stack exchange. The question may be similar, but if you read it again, you will see that I'm looking for the list of individual passengers names on a known ship (I'm giving the dates and names). On the ColeValleyGirl question, she is looking for a list of the name of the ships.  there is no answers for my question. I'm still not wiser than I was yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

Using [www.familysearch.org](http://www.familysearch.org), I found (was the only thing I found) this [microfilm](http://www.worldcat.org/title/registros-de-imigrantes-1808-1922/oclc/866463971).
The film (1808-1922) description states:

> Records of immigrants entering and leaving the port of Rio de Janeiro;
>   includes records of persons entering and leaving the immigrant
>   hostelry in Rio de Janeiro. Many of the record books include lists of
>   passengers and lists of ships.

Since it says it lists ships, and the date range covers your 1824, perhaps you could find your George Friedrich ship there, luckily.